# CSS Border issue on navigation menu bar

Tags: css

I thought my navigation bar css code bordeless but when I refresh the website window it still shows a blank betwin border of screen and the navigation bar (even I have a width at 100%)

[issue screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCQ4e.jpg)

```
ul {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Use `*{margin:0;padding:0;}` in css.

Answer (score 0):

i added  `left:0;` for `ul`

```
ul {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a CSS Reset to prevent automatic browser margins and paddings: 
https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Write a code from the link at the top of your CSS document